# Splash Plate, Sea Incense, Wave Incense, which is best?

Tags: pokemon-fourth-generation

I currently have 3 items—splash plate, wave incense, and sea incense—which all apparently increase the power of water-type moves.

I only plan on having one water-type pokémon in my party at a time, and I don't care about breeding at all. So, based on **power boost alone**, which of these is the best to use? Is there any general rule for ranking power boosts of these sorts of items?

In case it matters, my water-type moves are Surf, Waterfall, and Brine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[All](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Splash_Plate) [thee](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Wave_Incense) [in Gen 4](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Sea_Incense) (also, [Mystic Water](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mystic_Water))
boost the power of water type moves by 20%, so they are all functionally the same in battle.

The only difference between them in battle (for most Pokemon) is that is that if you [Fling](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Fling_(move)) the Splash Plate, Fling will have a base power of 90 (Mystic Water = 30, Incenses = 10). Arceus's type changes to water when the plate is held, and changes the type of its signature move, Judgement, to water.

Answer (score -1):

The splash plate is better because it gives a 20% increases in water type moves while the mystic water increases water type moves by 10%